# Parallax based on mousemove has different offset

Tags: javascript, parallax, mousemove

How can I have the same parallax offset in all the sections? Right now the offset increases as you add more `sections`. Note that in section `.two` and `.three` the parallax is different from section `.one`. I want section `.two` and `.three` to have the same parallax as in section `.one`. I am unsure what's causing the divs to go wider in section `.two` and `.three`.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/didacus/p4hrbdge/)

Thank you in advance.

JS

```
var currentX = '';
var currentY = '';
var movementConstant = .05;

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    var xToCenter = e.pageX - window.innerWidth/2;
    var yToCenter = e.pageY - window.innerHeight/2;

    $('.parallax div').each( function(i) {
      var $el = $(this);
      var newX  = (i + 1) * (xToCenter * movementConstant);
      var newY = (i + 1) * (yToCenter * movementConstant);      
      $el.css({left: newX + 'px', top: newY + 'px'});
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<section class="one">
  <div class="parallax">
      <div class="asset asset-layer4">4</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer3">3</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer2">2</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer1">1</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="two">
  <div class="parallax">
      <div class="asset asset-layer4">4</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer3">3</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer2">2</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer1">1</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="three">
  <div class="parallax">
      <div class="asset asset-layer4">4</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer3">3</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer2">2</div>
      <div class="asset asset-layer1">1</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.one,
.two,
.three {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.one { background-color: pink; }
.two { background-color: lightgray; }
.three { background-color: orange; }

.parallax {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    overflow: visible;
}
.asset {
    position: absolute;
}
.asset-layer1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.asset-layer2 {
  background-color: green;
}
.asset-layer3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.asset-layer4 {
  background-color: red;
}
body {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is that you are doing an each over ALL over the children div of .parallax. This means you are looping about 11 times. Each time you multiply by a larger i value, so it starts to look off.

Instead, what I have done is within each Parallax container, you will loop through it's children, giving you a value from  0-3. Now they are in sync!

https://jsfiddle.net/p4hrbdge/2/

```
   $('.parallax').each( function(i) {
        $(this).find('div').each(function(i) {
        var $el = $(this);
        var newX  = (i + 1) * (xToCenter * movementConstant);
        var newY = (i + 1) * (yToCenter * movementConstant);    
        $el.css({left: newX + 'px', top: newY + 'px'});
        })
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.